# Discord.py bot hosting on Heroku fails due to token issues

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

so I am trying to run this very simple discord bot(https://github.com/RapidKebab/hibot420) off Heroku, locally I can run it through cmd and it will run perfectly using dotenv and a .env file.

For Heroku, it wouldn't load dotenv, so the git version has the dotenv stuff commented out and replaced with what should pull the "DISCORD_TOKEN" from Heroku config vars, I am certain the token itself is correct, yet I get errors "401: Unauthorized" and "LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed." Apparently the latter is caused directly by the former.

Logs:

```
2019-10-24T16:14:37.910317+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-24T16:14:37.959627+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-10-24T16:14:37.77383+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-24T16:14:37.773868+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 256, in static_login
2019-10-24T16:14:37.774648+00:00 app[worker.1]:     data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
2019-10-24T16:14:37.774654+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 220, in request
2019-10-24T16:14:37.775561+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise HTTPException(r, data)
2019-10-24T16:14:37.775615+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized
2019-10-24T16:14:37.77562+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2019-10-24T16:14:37.775622+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2019-10-24T16:14:37.775623+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2019-10-24T16:14:37.775626+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-24T16:14:37.775649+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "bot.py", line 27, in <module>
2019-10-24T16:14:37.77648+00:00 app[worker.1]:     client.run(token)
2019-10-24T16:14:37.776484+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
2019-10-24T16:14:37.778024+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return future.result()
2019-10-24T16:14:37.778029+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
2019-10-24T16:14:37.778666+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
2019-10-24T16:14:37.77902+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
2019-10-24T16:14:37.780225+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
2019-10-24T16:14:37.780246+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
2019-10-24T16:14:37.782041+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
2019-10-24T16:14:37.782047+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 260, in static_login
2019-10-24T16:14:37.782977+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
2019-10-24T16:14:37.783003+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

Comment: The error is on line 42, you miss a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when I tried to host my bot using heroku, I verified my code again and again but the bot still didn't work. My error was in the env vars I put the token between quotes (because it's a string) but heroku used ' "your token" ' as the token so I tried to put in the var container my token without quotes and that worked. Maybe you are facing an other issue, in this case show more informations about your code, heroku settings, etc ...